# Multiple controls, apply CSS to selected one

Tags: css, asp.net

I have an aspx page with 3 Telerik RadGrids on it. On one of them I need to override the default styling which I have done with this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .RadGrid .rgHoveredRow {
        background: #25A0DA !important;
        color: white !important;
    }

    .rgAltRow, .rgRow {
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that this is applying the to all the radgrid controls.  How could this code be changed to apply it to only the radgrid control called `Radgrid1`?

Comment: Have a read of this: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the selectors with the grid's id

```
<style type="text/css">
    #Radgrid1.RadGrid .rgHoveredRow {
        background: #25A0DA !important;
        color: white !important;
    }

    #Radgrid1 .rgAltRow,
    #Radgrid1 .rgRow {
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
</style>
```

Depending on the resultant HTML you may need to change the first selector to `#Radgrid1 .RadGrid .rgHoveredRow` ***notice the extra space***

Answer (score 0):

"radgrid control called `Radgrid1`" you mean it's its name? if so -

```
.RadGrid[name=Radgrid1] .rgHoveredRow {
    background: #25A0DA !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks I've tried both solutions, its worked in that it now only applies styles to Radgrid1, but it has broken the styles itself, back text not white, grey hoover color not blue.

Comment: That's probably because of the `important!`, so it can't be overridden on hover.